# How to achieve mutual inductance and CM choke simulation in CircuitLab?

Tags: mutual-inductance, circuitlab

This site is using CircuitLab. In some SPICE programs it is possible to simulate CM choke. For example:

> Mutual Inductance is designated in a SPICE netlist by beginning the
>   first word (label) of a new line with the letter "K".  It is unique
>   among the basic circuit elements in LTspice in that a schematic symbol
>   is not used to represented it.

Is there a way to achieve this by using CircuitLab?

Comment: Is it even possible?

Comment: You could use a pair of voltage-controlled-voltage-sources (VCVS) in series with inductors but it is clumsy. https://www.circuitlab.com/forums/modeling-and-simulation/topic/75exru43/coupling-inductors/    Spice or Falstad Simulator it is far easier to define coupling ratio.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist This CircuitLab is very limited.

Comment: that's why I refuse to use it for simulation

Answer (score 2):

(CircuitLab simulation engine author here -- just noticed this question!)
CircuitLab does support coupled inductors. Define a **Parameter Element** with a name like "K L1 L2". For example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxmEX2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sub>(Example adapted from: [https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece222/How%20to%20create%20a%20transformer%20using%20LTSpice.pdf](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Etymerski/ece222/How%20to%20create%20a%20transformer%20using%20LTSpice.pdf))</sub>

It can also handle multiple inductors, and you can even do parameter sweeps over the coupling coefficient, for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW5AcO.png)</sup>

<sub>(Example adapted from: [https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece222/How%20to%20create%20a%20transformer%20using%20LTSpice.pdf](https://web.cecs.pdx.edu/%7Etymerski/ece222/How%20to%20create%20a%20transformer%20using%20LTSpice.pdf))</sub>

Lp, Ls1, Ls2 effectively form a center-tapped transformer. If you run the simulation, this second example shows a parameter sweep which allows you to compare the results for different values of the coupling coefficient.

Comment: Hi @compumike Could you take a look at this question? Thanks. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/686491/is-circuitlabs-coupled-inductor-code-broken