# Is CircuitLab's coupled inductor code broken?

Tags: circuitlab

I was working on an answer for [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/686187/268467), using CircuitLab but getting inexplicable results. The circuit oscillated, but the voltages were off. I was using CircuitLab's coupled inductor feature described [on this page](https://www.circuitlab.com/docs/circuit-elements/), and discussed in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/552164/268467). To make the issue easier to debug, I have reproduced the problem in a very simple circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftjwup.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The switch closes at t = 1 sec. Here are the simulation results

[image]

[image]

Yes, the voltage scale is in MV and the current scale is in kA! (That poor 1\$k\Omega\$ resistor!)

Anyway, if you delete the parameter block

> K L1 L2 = 1

the behavior is much more normal.

[image]

[image]

I believe that I used the coupled inductor feature in the past without problem, but it may have been that the circuit I was modeling simply didn't express the bug that I am seeing today.

I will happily delete this post if/when a CircuitLab developer has been made aware of the issue. However, I hope that it can remain visible until such a developer can see it.

Tim Williams has made an interesting observation that might be useful in tracking down the bug. If a small resistor is placed between the two inductors, the problem appears to vanish. In the circuit below, I have added a 1 \$\mu\Omega\$ resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fi78YD.png)</sup>

With this very minor change the simulation seems normal.

[image]
[image]

This suggests that the coupled conductors sharing a common node is an essential part of the bug. (Thanks Tim!)

Comment: @compumike I am tagging you on this post because you responded to a previous question where you identified yourself as a CircuitLab developer. If you still are, could you take a look?

Comment: You can't summon someone from out of thread like that. You'll need to find another way to get ahold of them, unless they look into this thread.

Comment: Hmm, adding a negligible-value resistor in series between the inductors (yes, in the middle) seems to help. But the K value itself seems to be broken, or at least it doesn't respond to reasonable values like -1 to 0.